# Trouble in solving simultaneous equations with subscripts

Tags: subscript

My goal is to solve equation with subscripts. But the result shows {{}}.
Strange enough, If I don't use subscripts, result shows.
Is there a limitation in using subscripts?
How to fix code below?

This code doesn't work. How to fix to use subscript?

```
 Clear["Global`*"]
 Solve[Subscript[y, 1] == Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 2] && 
  Subscript[y, 2] == Subscript[x, 1]/(
   Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 2]), {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 
  2]}]
```

This code works with no subscript.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Solve[y1 == x1 + x2 && y2 == x1/(x1 + x2), {x1, x2}]
```

Comment: Don't use subscripts. Subscripts are primarily a formatting command. Use arrays a[[1]], a[[2]].. or functions a[1], a[2], instead

Comment: If you really need the output to have subscripts, you can use what @bills recommends and then convert to subscripts at the end:  `sol = Solve[y[1] == x[1] + x[2] && y[2] == x[1]/(x[1] + x[2]), {x[1], x[2]}];
sol /. x[i_] -> Subscript[x, i] /. y[i_] -> Subscript[y, i]`.

Comment: MMA version 12.1  Both calculations work for me.

Comment: You can format the display of indexed variables with subscripts, e.g., `Clear["Global\`*"]; Format[x[n_]] := Subscript[x, n]; Format[y[n_]] := Subscript[y, n]; Solve[y[1] == x[1] + x[2] && y[2] == x[1]/(x[1] + x[2]), {x[1], x[2]}]`

Answer (score 1):

The output of your code would print as a list of associations showing the solution for x_1 and x_2. In regards to the {{}} present in the solution, this is the output of Solve[] when the there are multiple solutions.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html

If you want to shorten what you typed, you can use the keyboard shortcut ctrl+- to type the subscript in line.

Answer (score 1):

The command Clear["Global`*"] does not clear the subscripts.  You need to enter $a_1=.$ and so forth.  Consider the commands:

```
Subscript[myA, 1] = 5;
Clear["Global`*"]
Subscript[myA, 1]
Subscript[myA, 1] =.
Subscript[myA, 1]
```

After assigning $myA_1=5$ and executing the Clear command, $myA_1$ still is assigned the value of 5.  However, once the command $myA_1=.$ is executed, the subscript $myA_1$ is cleared.  If your Solve didn't work, I suspect your subscripted variables had previously been assigned.  Always a good idea when you have a problem you can't figure out, consider isolating the code and running it on a clean Kernel (save it as a file, close Mathematica and then re-run it.

When I run your command with code to first clear say 10 subscripted variables for x and y:

```
Quiet[
  (Subscript[x, #] =.) & /@ Range[10];
  (Subscript[y, #] =.) & /@ Range[10];
  ];

mySol = {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]} /. 
  Solve[Subscript[y, 1] == Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 2] && 
    Subscript[y, 2] == 
     Subscript[x, 1]/(Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 2]), {Subscript[
     x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]}]
```

I get:

```
{{Subscript[y, 1] Subscript[y, 2], 
  Subscript[y, 1] - Subscript[y, 1] Subscript[y, 2]}}
```

with $x_1=mySol[[1]]$ and $y_1=mySol[[2]]$.